# RewriteCond using .htaccess to redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xss

How to redirect below url and match with RewriteCond

```
    http://example.com/team/home/index.cgi/"><script>alert(7229)</script>
    http://example.com/team/home/index.cgi/?"onmouseover="alert(173)"
```

i need RewriteCond which can match the above url and redirect to rewriterule which is set for other RewriteCond's

```
Updated query for .htaccess file, please check below code is written for xxs,sql injection prevention, but not solving problem completley 
------------------------------------------------------

Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On


#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Chrome.* [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Firefox.* [NC]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark).* [NC,OR]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./\.\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/script/i$  [NE,L]
#RewriteRule ^([^\"]+\.cgi)/.* $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/team/home/index.cgi? [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#END OF XSS FIX
```

Comment: Unclear what you want. Can you clarify with a bit more clarity.

Comment: actually i am looking to prevent this URL from xss, for query string 
this conditions works fine RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR], but the above URL doesn't contain query string, i am now unable to prevent this url against xss for this i need a RewriteCond not a rewriterule so that my other conditions also gets redirected to index.cgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check for `REQUEST_URI` in addition to `QUERY_STRING`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./\.\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} onmouseover [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: i did this but not getting any success on it,remains on same page.
and also i need condition for /?"onmouseover="alert(173)" also

Comment: you mean to say it RewriteCond will not work here because of RewriteBase, but its working fine for query string urls

Comment: where should i place RewriteBase, i changed it above or pls suggest me

Comment: Hi Anubhava,
how you doin?
have small query regarding Multiviews
if server is Upgrade to the latest version of Apache web server, or disable MultiViews in the Apache httpd.conf
will this impact my above code in .httaccess in my directory also? or it will impact in all directory and above conditions will get failed is that right?

Comment: can i stop effects of multiviews disable in my directory? with some code if yes then pls guide me.

Comment: should is use 'Options -MultiViews' above RewriteEngine On ? to disable effects httpconfig.file?

Comment: `Options -MultiViews` at top of this .htaccess will work fine